# manipulate a matlab file with python

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, scipy

i have a .mat file containing annotations for some images, I need to read and manipulate specified values from this file using python and am stuck I tried to use h5py it doesn't work for me. with scipy I can read the file and print the whole file but I can't get a specified value.
I captured the structure of my mat file using octave can anyone help me to get the BBox values for each ImgName and save them into a variable.
[screen shot of the annotation.mat file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q6Mv4.png)

Comment: So are you saying the `io.loadmat` does run?  If so you need to provide more information on what it produces.  MATLAB matrices map on to `numpy` arrays fairly well (with a possible `order` difference).  `cells` and `struct` produce more complicated `numpy` arrays.

Comment: io.loadmat works well i did a print("annotation") and it return all values of my file. but when i try to get the BBox for a specified value it doesnt work maybe its because the BBox is a struct and the ImgName is just a cell. is there anyway to solve this please (this is my first time i use python and machine learning )

Comment: Is there to solve this?  Someone with access to your file can probably figure out how the data is stored.  But I won't even try to guess.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved using this ( it may help some beginners like me) :

```
import scipy.io as spio
anno=spio.loadmat('annotation_1.mat')
#BBox.  X y
#print(anno['annot'][0][1][0])
listX=anno['annot'][0][1][0]
print(listX[1][1])
#ImgName
#print(anno['annot'][0][1][1])
img=anno['annot'][0][1][1]
print(img)
```